# regex matching algorithm on count occurrences

Tags: regex, if-statement, solr

I spent ours on getting the solution for my little regex problem.

Assuming I have a string containing german umlauts. e.g. "Brötchenkörbe".

I need the best regex condition to match ALL 'ö' except the last one, if the occurrence of 'ö' is > 1

(else) If there is only ONE 'ö' in the string, I want to match that character as well.

So that I would get the following results:

Br**ö**tchenkörbe

M**ö**hrenl**ö**sungslöcher

L**ö**schwagen

I found an expression that does match every 'ö', except the last one. But the is no match, if the 'ö' occures only one time:

```
/(ö(?=[^.]*[ö]))/
```

does anyone get the trick?

I need that expression to work on a filter on my solr server.

Background: I use a stemm-Filter to stemm words in german.  but the used filter "SnowballPorterFilter" does change every umlaut (öäüÖÄÜ) to (oauOAU).

Only the last umlaut need to be changed from that filter, so that I want to use a regex-filter ("PatternReplaceFilterFactory") which protects all other umlauts from that change, and reverse that protection after running that stemm-filter.

e.g.:  Möhrenlösungslöcher gets "M#o#hrenl#o#sungslöcher" , filter does "M#o#hrenl#o#sungsloch" , and then reverse protection to "Möhrenlösungsloch"

Comment: What language/tool are you using this regex in?

Comment: I'm really curious what *Möhrenlösungslöcher* are :-)

Comment: hehe... I use regexr.com to test it. I need that expression on solr server for the PatternReplaceFilterFactory. "Möhrenlösungslöcher" -> that word makes no sense, but does exactly explain my needs ;)

Comment: After thinking about it, it must have something to do with a bottling plant for baby food…

Comment: ;) Where is Robins post gone? the last regex runs on my filter. but I can´t find where to place the replacement part ...

Comment: Are you aware of [the German stemmers](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/tree/lucene_solr_4_8/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/de) that exist in Solr? I post this as comment, as it does not solve your regex question.

Comment: Your regex seems to work well on [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/390ps). Substitution seems to work properly if you just put `#o#` in the substitution field. I suppose I'm missing something… what's wrong with the replacement part?

Comment: '(^[^ö]*)ö|ö(?![^ö]*$)' that works in regexr. correct. but it matches all characters from the beginning to the first matching 'ö' as well. So substitution kills all those leading letters.

Comment: I was just thinking about your `/(ö(?=[^.]*[ö]))/` regex. It seems to work (with global `g` flag on) and to match only the `ö`s for me (please use @Qeole in case you answer to me, in this way I'll be notified).

Comment: ok, right. but thats not my whole solution. ... as I explained, I just need to change the '/(^[^ö]*)ö|ö(?![^ö]*$)/gm' expression, so that the leading letters to the 1st matching 'ö' wont be eaten..... Anyone who can help me to change that? thank u

Comment: Hmmm… Maybe try this: `/(^([^ö]*))ö|ö(?![^ö]*$)/gm`, replaced by `$1#o#`?

Comment: Hey THAT was it. Thank u very much ;) AND it works in solr-filter. yieeha

Comment: Glad to hear that! :-) You could make it an answer to your own post, maybe.

Comment: But as I see, it ist not that easy to change that expression now, to fit for all umlauts ö,ä,ü. ....

Comment: Yes it's gonna be difficult to do all this with a single regex. Maybe you could try to do it in several steps: 1) `/(^([^äöü]*))(ä|ö|ü)|(ä|ö|ü)(?![^äöü]*$)/gm`, replacing with `$1#$3$4#` -> all umlauts to fix are between `#` signs; 2) change all `#ä#` to `#a#`; 3) repeat for `#ö#` and `#ü#`. Would that work?

Comment: That´s it. You´re my man :) Thank you alot!!!

Answer (score 1):

Qeole got the solution:

In three steps:

1. Place umlauts to fix between `#` signs with following regex:

   ```
   /(^([^äöü]*))(ä|ö|ü)|(ä|ö|ü)(?![^äöü]*$)/gm
   ```

   (replace with `$1#$3$4#`)
   All umlauts to fix are now between `#` signs. So let's keep going…
2. Change all `#ä#` to `#a#`.
3. Repeat for `#ö#` and `#ü#`.